# Showing an abelian pro-$p$ group is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ module

Tags: modules, p-adic-number-theory

I am rather new to $p$-adics, and I am trying to show that every abelian pro-$p$ group is a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ module. I know some partial answers already exist ([About pro-$p$ groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906596/about-pro-p-groups)), but I am having trouble understanding how the module operation is defined and why it works.

My understanding of the problem is:

- We are given an abelian pro-$p$ group $G = \lim\limits_{\longleftarrow} G_i$, defined additively. An arbitrary element of $G$ therefore looks like $(\dots, g_2, g_1, g_0)$ where each $g_i$ has order a power of $p$ in $G_i$.
- An arbitrary element $x$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can be expressed as $x_0 + x_1p+ x_2p^2 + \dots$, and identified with $(\dots, x_2, x_1, x_0)$, with each $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

I would like to define $x \cdot g$ so that it satisfies the module axioms. The link above says from what I understand that $x \cdot g := (\dots, (x_0 + x_1p + x_2p^2) \cdot g_2, (x_0 + x_1p) \cdot g_1, x_0 \cdot g_0)$ where $n \cdot g_i$ is understood as $g_i + \dots + g_i$, added $n$ times. However, although the other axioms are fine, I have no idea why $(xy) \cdot g = x \cdot (y \cdot g)$.

Do I have the correct operation? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: First of all, you really need matching $p$-powers, i.e. $g_i$ should have order $p^{i+1}$. Then, it would be immensely helpful (and now possible due to that order matching) to view what you write as $x_0+...+x_i p^i$ as element of $\mathbb Z/(p^{i+1})$, which has a ring structure.

Comment: Is the fact that $g_i$ has order $p^{i+1}$ implicitely assumed when talking about a pro-$p$ group? My definition only says each $G_i$ is discrete finite of order a power of $p$

Comment: Depends on source I guess. If not, i.e. you just assume all $g_i$ have order $k_i$, then you have to multiply them with $x_0 + ... + x_{k_i-1}p^{k_i-1} \in \mathbb Z/p^{k_i}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the comments, I'll try doing it now

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer a more conceptual but perhaps sloppier strategy for handling this.

Let $g$ be an element of your abelian pro-$p$-group $G$. What you know is that $\{p^ng\}$ is a sequence with limit $0_G$. Well, let $z\in\Bbb Z_p$; you are asking how to define $zg$. First, express $z$ as a $p$-adic limit of integers, $\{m_i\}$, so that $\{m_i-m_{i-1}\}\to0$, $p$-adically. Then it should be easy enough to show that $\{m_ig\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $G$. The limit of this sequence should be your $zg$.